# How can I find the center the hole with hough circles

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

For this image, I tried to use hough cirlce to find the center of the "black hole".

[image]

After playing with the parameters of `cv2.HoughCircles` for a long time, the following is the best I can get.

raw image:
[image]

[image]

```
# reproducible code for stackoverflow
import cv2
import os
import sys
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# read image can turn it gray
img = cv2.imread(FILE)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img_gray = dst = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.figure(figsize = (18,18))
plt.imshow(cimg, cmap = "gray")

# removing noises
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 5))
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(y, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, element,  iterations = 7)
plt.figure(figsize = (12,12))
plt.imshow(closing, cmap = "gray")

# try to find the circles

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(closing,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,3,50,
                            param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=20,maxRadius=50)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
plt.figure(figsize = (12,12))
plt.imshow(cimg)
```

Update::

The one with Canny:

```
edges = cv2.Canny(closing, 100, 300)
plt.figure(figsize = (12,12))
plt.imshow(edges, cmap = "gray")
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(edges,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,2,50,
                            param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=20,maxRadius=60)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
plt.figure(figsize = (12,12))
plt.imshow(cimg)
```

[image]
[image]

Still not the right circle that is wanted.

---

Update:

@crackanddie

Sometimes there is 6 or 9 in the identity number.
The circle in 6 or 9 is not very round.
Is there any way to filter that out?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `HoughCircles` after `Canny` edge detection?

Comment: Yes, it's updated in the post.

Comment: If you are using the raw image that you've posted (~ 2500x1800) then you need to increase the radius to about ~80 or so. If your 'closing' image has a visible circle then Hough transform should be able to detect it.

Comment: answer for the last question update: I think there is no good way to do this,but if usually this circle is in the middle or on the left side of the picture, then you can simply cut off the right. But it is quite stupid way. Another way - you can try to use CMYK color space as @eldesgraciado said or LAB color space and set threshold to good values so this brown peaces could be filtered by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative method if you do not want to implement or fiddle with Hough's parameters. You must be sure there's at least one circle visible in your picture. The idea is to create a segmentation mask based on the [CMYK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) color space and filter the blobs of interest by circularity and area. These are the steps:

1. Convert the image from `BGR` to `CMYK`
2. Threshold the `K` channel to get a binary mask
3. Filter blobs by `circularity` and `area`
4. Approximate the filtered blobs as circles

I'm choosing the `CMYK` color space because the circle is mostly black. The `K` (key) channel (in this case - black) should do a good job of representing the blob of interest, albeit, with some noise - as usual. Let's see the code:

```
# Imports:
import cv2
import numpy as np

# image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"
fileName = "dyj3O.jpg"

# load image
bgr = cv2.imread(path + fileName)
```

Alright, we need to convert the image from `BGR` to `CMYK`. `OpenCV` does not offer the conversion, so we need to do it manually. The [formula](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-cmyk.html) is very straightforward. I'm just interested on the `K` channel, so I just calculate it like this:

```
# Make float and divide by 255:
bgrFloat = bgr.astype(np.float) / 255.

# Calculate K as (1 - whatever is biggest out of bgrFloat)
kChannel = 1 - np.max(bgrFloat, axis=2)

# Convert back to uint 8:
kChannel = 255 * kChannel
kChannel = kChannel.astype(np.uint8)
```

Gotta keep en eye on the `data types`, because there are `float` operations going on. This is the result:

[image]

As you see, the hole is almost 100% white, that's cool, we can threshold this image via Otsu like this:

```
# Compute binary mask of the hole via Otsu:
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(kChannel, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Which gives you this nice binary mask:

[image]

Now, here comes the *laborious* part. Let's find `contours` on this image. For every contour/blob compute `circularity` and `area`. Use this info to filter noise and get the contour of interest, keep in mind that a perfect circle should have `circularity` close to `1.0`. Once you get a contour of interest, approximate a circle to it. This is the process:

```
# Find the big contours/blobs on the filtered image:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binaryImage, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Store the detected circles here:
detectedCircles = []

# Look for the potential contours of interest:
for _, c in enumerate(contours):

    # Get the blob's area and perimeter:
    contourArea = cv2.contourArea(c)
    contourPerimeter = cv2.arcLength(c, True)

    # Compute circularity:
    if contourPerimeter > 0:
        circularity = (4 * 3.1416 * contourArea) / (pow(contourPerimeter, 2))
    else:
        circularity = 0.0

    # Set the min threshold values to identify the
    # blob of interest:
    minCircularity = 0.7
    minArea = 2000

    if circularity >= minCircularity and contourArea >= minArea:

        # Approximate the contour to a circle:
        (x, y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)

        # Compute the center and radius:
        center = (int(x), int(y))

        # Cast radius to in:
        radius = int(radius)

        # Store the center and radius:
        detectedCircles.append([center, radius])

        # Draw the circles:
        cv2.circle(bgr, center, radius, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("Detected Circles", bgr)

print("Circles Found: " + str(len(detectedCircles)))
```

Additionally, I have stored the circle (`center` and `radius`) in the `detectedCircles` list. This is the final result:

[image]

```
Circles Found: 1
```

Comment: if my actual image has height 1942 and width 2590, is there any number I need to adjust accordingly in the script?

Comment: After many trials, your circularity computation is the key to the final stable solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2


def threshold_gray_const(image_, rang: tuple):
    return cv2.inRange(image_, rang[0], rang[1])


def binary_or(image_1, image_2):
    return cv2.bitwise_or(image_1, image_2)


def negate_image(image_):
    return cv2.bitwise_not(image_)


def particle_filter(image_, power):
    # Abdrakov's particle filter
    nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image_, connectivity=8)
    sizes = stats[1:, -1]
    nb_components = nb_components - 1

    min_size = power

    img2 = np.zeros(output.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(0, nb_components):
        if sizes[i] >= min_size:
            img_to_compare = threshold_gray_const(output, (i + 1, i + 1))
            img2 = binary_or(img2, img_to_compare)

    img2 = img2.astype(np.uint8)
    return img2


def reject_borders(image_):
    # Abdrakov's border rejecter
    out_image = image_.copy()
    h, w = image_.shape[:2]
    for row in range(h):
        if out_image[row, 0] == 255:
            cv2.floodFill(out_image, None, (0, row), 0)
        if out_image[row, w - 1] == 255:
            cv2.floodFill(out_image, None, (w - 1, row), 0)
    for col in range(w):
        if out_image[0, col] == 255:
            cv2.floodFill(out_image, None, (col, 0), 0)
        if out_image[h - 1, col] == 255:
            cv2.floodFill(out_image, None, (col, h - 1), 0)
    return out_image


src = cv2.imread("your_image")
img_gray = dst = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img_gray, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, element,  iterations=2)
tv, thresh = cv2.threshold(closing, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
neg = negate_image(thresh)
rej = reject_borders(neg)
filtered = particle_filter(rej, 300)
edges = cv2.Canny(filtered, 100, 200)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(edges, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 3, 50, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=20, maxRadius=50)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0, :]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(src, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(src, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)

cv2.imshow("closing", closing)
cv2.imshow("edges", edges)
cv2.imshow("out", src)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I changed `cv2.morphologyEx` parameters a bit, because they were too strong. And after this noise removing I made a binary image using `cv2.THRESH_OTSU` parameter, negated it, rejected borders and filtered a bit. Then I used `cv2.Canny` to find edges and this 'cannied' image I passed into `cv2.HoughCircles`. If any questions - ask me :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer. I also added a question in my original post. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a "thinking out of the box" solution then check this solution out. Remember this might have a few false positives in some cases and would only work in cases where circle contour is complete or joined.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import pi

pi_eps = 0.1

rgb = cv2.imread('/path/to/your/image/find_circle.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,21,5)

contours, hier = cv2.findContours(th.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
out_img = rgb.copy()

for i in range(len(contours)):        
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[i])
    ar = min(w,h)/max(w,h)
    # For a circle aspect ratio is close to 1.0
    # In your use case circle diameter is between 40px-100px
    if ar < 0.9 or \
    w < 40 or w > 100:
        continue
    
    # P = 2 * PI * r
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(contours[i], True)
    if perimeter == 0:
        continue
    # Second level confirmation could be done using PI = P * P / (4 * A)
    # A = PI * r * r
    area = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
    if area == 0:
        continue
    # d = (w+h) / 2 average diameter
    # A contour is a circle if (P / d) = PI
    ctr_pi = perimeter / ((w+h) / 2)
    
    if abs(ctr_pi - pi) < pi_eps * pi:
        cv2.circle(out_img, (int(x+w/2), int(y+h/2)), int(max(w,h)/2), (0, 255, 0), 1)
        print("Center of the circle: ", x + w/2, y+h/2)

plt.imshow(out_img)
```

[image: Detected Circle]